# Logs to check when the plugin was first installed for the first time

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Is there a way to check when for the first time a particular plugin was installed in the WordPress?

I need this information to prove my integrity somewhere.

Comment: sounds like a trust issue. Regardless of any technical way to prove a point, it is unlikely to improve trust. The best way to gain trust is communication (probably too late here)

Comment: Someone is trying to manipulate, subjugate, and get rid of customer care by reverse engineering a fake allegation despite I am a legitimate buyer.

Comment: again the problem is trust. Whatever would be the answer people that have root access will always be able to manipulate the information, so if there is no trust you might just be accused in manipulating it. but lets cut it here as this discussion is very off topic (but you are welcome to "the loop" chat room and give some more details, maybe someone will have a good advice)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When plugins were activated is not logged by WordPress. If the plugin hasn't been updated then the file modified time in the file system might be useful for telling you when the plugin was at least uploaded.

If you have regular database backups then you could look at `active_plugins` in `wp_options` to get an idea of when plugins were activated based on which backup the plugin first appears in.

Comment: Can the information be fetched from hosting Cpanel somehow?

Comment: does WP stores plugin update information?

Comment: If you have access to phpmyadmin you can create an extra table  (i.e.'plugin_activation_track') and  store information about name, version and time of activation using `register_activation_hook` that runs at every activation ( upgrades also ) https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook , just an idea..of course it 's probably too late

Comment: Re: cPanel, you'd need to ask your host if they log anything like that. No, WordPress does not log plugin update information.